# How to find out which attribute having error in XML validating by using XSD and Validate Mediator in WSO2

Tags: validation, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to achieve XML message validation in WSO2 by using Validate Mediator. XSD is saved in Governance registry.For error in one attribute I am able to Print the log.But if the XML having 2-3 erroneous attributes How can I display it.Like how can I get in which attributes there is error?

My code is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="Seq4" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<validate>
    <schema key="gov:/as_uil/MT564_XSD.xsd"/>
    <on-fail>
        <sequence key="Error_Seq"/>
    </on-fail>
</validate>
</sequence>
```

If having error in source field I am getting below output:

```
[2017-09-08 16:21:37,120] [] ERROR - LogMediator Error_Message = *******************Invalid Source***************
```